# Why does Visual Studio 2017 open Windows "For developers" settings on startup?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

Every time I start VS 2017 (Enterprise) on Windows 10, it opens the *Settings > Update & security > For developers* screen. Why does it do this, and how can I prevent it?

Installed workloads:

- .NET desktop
- UWP
- .NET mobile (Xamarin)

I don't recall changing anything else during installation.

Comment: VS these days is a rather complex beast and the number of different possible installed configurations I wouldn't care to hazard a guess at. Can you update your question with which workload(s) and individual components you've installed in *your* installation.

Comment: Shoot, as soon as I navigated there by hand it decided to install something and is now waiting for a reboot.  Thanks a lot :)  You ought to tell us what you got selected there, non-zero odds that Xamarin wants an emulator or whatnot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the exact same problem when opening a Xamarin project.
(Maybe it's related to the configuration request of the Xamarin Mac Agent)

> I've found that enabling the developer mode on the settings stop the
>   panel to popup everytime.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It shows up because of the UWP workload (along with a notification in Visual Studio that you need a developer license to develop UWP apps):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

> However, if you are writing software with Visual Studio on a computer for first time, you *will* need to enable Developer Mode on both the development PC, and on any devices you'll use to test your code. Opening a UWP project when Developer Mode is not enabled will either open the **For developers** settings page, or cause this dialog to appear in Visual Studio:
>
> [image: Enable Developer Mode for Windows 10]

> - *Developer mode* lets you sideload apps, and also run apps from Visual Studio in debug mode.

Either switching to developer mode or modifying your Visual Studio installation to not include UWP will stop it from happening.